# accelerating a Gaussian blur of floats with NEON intrinsics

Tags: c++, image-processing, assembly, neon, gaussianblur

i want to accelerate some part of an algorithm(gaussianblur filter) in arm and i decided to use **SIMD** with **NEON intrinsic**.
but unfortunately that code have written with NEON is very slower than the pure cpp code .
these are the pure cpp code and NEON version of code.
is it possible improve it?

pure cpp:

```
inline void GaussianBlur_5x5_row(const float __restrict_arr *in, float __restrict_arr *out, const unsigned int cols)
{
    //Left columns
    out[0] = (in[0]+in[2])*0.054488685f + (in[0]+in[1])*0.24420135f + in[0]*0.40261996f;
    out[1] = (in[0]+in[3])*0.054488685f + (in[0]+in[2])*0.24420135f + in[1]*0.40261996f;

    //Middle columns 
    for (unsigned int j=2; j<cols-2; j+=1)
    {
        out[j] = (in[j-2]+in[j+2])*0.054488685f + (in[j-1]+in[j+1])*0.24420135f + in[j]*0.40261996f;
        out[j+1] = (in[j-1]+in[j+3])*0.054488685f + (in[j]+in[j+2])*0.24420135f + in[j+1]*0.40261996f;


    }
    //Right columns
    out[cols-2] = (in[cols-4]+in[cols-1])*0.054488685f + (in[cols-3]+in[cols-1])*0.24420135f + in[cols-2]*0.40261996f;
    out[cols-1] = (in[cols-3]+in[cols-1])*0.054488685f + (in[cols-2]+in[cols-1])*0.24420135f + in[cols-1]*0.40261996f;
}
```

with NEON intrinsic:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

//kernels coefficients for sigma =1  and  kernel_size =5

float32x4_t coef_1 = { 0.054488685f , 0.122100675f , 0.20130998f , 0.122100675f };
float32x4_t coef_2 = { 0.122100675f , 0.20130998f  , 0.122100675f, 0.054488685f };

float32x4_t load_1 ,
            load_2 ,
            load_3 ,
            help_1 ,
            help_2 ,
            help_3 ;

float32x2_t a     ,
            dst_1 ,
            dst_2 ;

inline void GaussianBlur5x5_row_NEON_128bit_2_itr( const float __restrict_arr *in, float __restrict_arr *out, const unsigned int cols)
{
    //Left columns
    out[0] = (in[0]+in[2])*0.054488685f + (in[0]+in[1])*0.24420135f + in[0]*0.40261996f;
    out[1] = (in[0]+in[3])*0.054488685f + (in[0]+in[2])*0.24420135f + in[1]*0.40261996f;

    //Middle columns
    for (unsigned int j=2; j<cols-2; j+=2)
    {

     load_1 = vld1q_f32( &in[j-2] );
     load_2 = vld1q_f32( &in[j-1] );
     load_3 = vld1q_f32( &in[j  ] );

     help_1 = vmulq_f32( load_1 , coef_1 );
     help_2 = vmulq_f32( load_2 , coef_2 );
     help_3 = vaddq_f32( help_1 , help_2 );
     a      = vadd_f32 ( vget_high_f32( help_3 ) ,  vget_low_f32( help_3 ) );
     dst_1  = vpadd_f32( a , a );

     help_1 = vmulq_f32( load_2 , coef_1 );
     help_2 = vmulq_f32( load_3 , coef_2 );
     help_3 = vaddq_f32( help_1 , help_2 );
     a      = vadd_f32 ( vget_high_f32( help_3 ) ,  vget_low_f32( help_3 ) );
     dst_2  = vpadd_f32( a , a );

     out[j  ] = dst_1[0];
     out[j+1] = dst_2[0];
    }
    //Right columns
    out[cols-2] = (in[cols-4]+in[cols-1])*0.054488685f + (in[cols-3]+in[cols-1])*0.24420135f + in[cols-2]*0.40261996f;
    out[cols-1] = (in[cols-3]+in[cols-1])*0.054488685f + (in[cols-2]+in[cols-1])*0.24420135f + in[cols-1]*0.40261996f;
}
```

Comment: (1) Which specific ARM architecture is being targeted? (2) Which compiler is being used, and what are the compilation switches used for invocation of the compiler?

Comment: arm cortex a53 is targeted and for compilation im using gcc 8.3 compiler with -o3 optimization flag

Comment: I still can't get the code to compile. Please add the *complete* compiler command line to the question so others can reproduce your observations.

Comment: for compile this part of code you need to have all of headfiles and .... .if it`s possible give me your email address to send all of it

Comment: Just looking at your pure C++ code: the “middle columns” are each computed twice, seems rather wasteful. Is that loop supposed to say `j+=2`?

Comment: yes you are right. accidentally i forgot to save last  changes in cpp code

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> float32x4_t load_1 ,
>             load_2 ,
>             load_3 ,
>             help_1 ,
>             help_2 ,
>             help_3 ;
>
> float32x2_t a     ,
>             dst_1 ,
>             dst_2 ;
> ```

These should be local variables, for both software-engineering and performance reasons.

When the are global variables, the resulting assembly code is littered with redundant `vstr` instructions.

Comment: So should the constants like `coef_1` - let compilers handle them the same way they do string literals.  Non-const global is horrible for constants, too, especially when you read them in a loop that has stores to unknown `float*`.